# How to make handler static to avoid leak, when I call non static methods from it?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, static, handler

So I have a service which performs communication with some hardware via bluetooth. Service contains a Handler for receiving messages from Activities. This messages are commands/instruction for service what to do. Handler is simply defined as:

```
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            switch (msg){
            case: blahblah ....
               break;
            case: blahblah ....
               break;
            }
  }
}
```

Everything actually works without problems BUT lint gave me warning that leak might occur and I should make this Handler static...

> *This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur. 
>   Issue: Ensures that Handler classes do not hold on to a reference to an outer
>   class Id: HandlerLeak In Android, Handler classes should be static or
>   leaks might occur. Messages enqueued on the application thread's
>   MessageQueue also retain their target Handler. If the Handler is an
>   inner class, its outer class will be retained as well. To avoid
>   leaking the outer class, declare the Handler as a static nested class
>   with a WeakReference to its outer class.*

My problem is that I can't simply make Handler static cause I am calling non static methods depending of which message came to service. Some methods are calling other methods and there are a lot of them so it is impossible that I would need to make them all static, no?

Here I would need advice from you more experienced developers. How to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: add a weak ref to a outer class

Answer (score 1):

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){...}
```

You don't need to create a Java class, just create a handler and override handleMessage method between those brackets

```
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage (Message msg){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is very necessary to make the handler static. You could declare a 'static class XXXHandler extends Handler', then the handler (target of Message) would not keep a reference to the enclosing class. Then it won't be leaked. 
   If you want to pass something in the Message, then put them into Message.object. If there are multiple objects to be processed by the handler, just put them in  an Object[], and use force conversion when you want to use them.
   I found a problem like this before. :)